# NodeJS - Nested async functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, nested

in an express router .post which is async, I have this line:

```
var recaptcha = await tokenValidate(req);
```

tokenValidate is below:

```
async function tokenValidate(req) {
   
    // some code to generate a URL with a private key, public key, etc.
    
    return await tokenrequest(url);
  
}
```

Then tokenrequest is below: (note request is the npm request library)

```
async function tokenrequest(url) {
    request(url, function(err, response, body){
        //the body is the data that contains success message
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        
        //check if the validation failed
        if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success){
             return false;
          }
        
        //if passed response success message to client
         return true;
        
      })
}
```

Issue is the nested async functions. The initial recaptcha variable returns undefined since 'request' doesn't resolve, even though I'm using await. How can I get recaptcha to wait for tokenValidate which in turn has to wait for tokenrequest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tokenRequest()` function is returning a promise (because it's `async`), but that promise resolves immediately with no value that is attached to your call to `request()`.   And, the `return` values you do have are just returning to the `request()` callback where they are ignored, not from your actual top level function.

What I would suggest is that you ditch the `request()` module because it's [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and does not support promises and pick a [new more modern module](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) that does support promises. I use the [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) module which would make this whole thing a LOT easier and a lot fewer lines of code.

```
const got = require('got');

async function tokenrequest(url) {
    let result = await got(url).json();
    return !!result.success;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple issues:

- Your `tokenrequest` function is not returning anything (the return value in the `request` callback function won't be returned)
- `await tokenrequest(url);` won't work as you expect because the `request` library is using a callback (not async/await)

This can be fixed by returning a Promise:

```js
async function tokenrequest(url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (err, response, body) {
      //the body is the data that contains success message
      body = JSON.parse(body);
        
      //check if the validation failed
      if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
        resolve(false);
       
      } else {
        //if passed response success message to client
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Much better to ditch the deprecated `request()` library and use one of the [more modern libraries](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) that support promises.

Comment: In your suggested code with `request()`, if you're going to call `JSON.parse()` on a foreign string, you have to `try/catch` around it to catch parsing errors and you also need to check the `err` parameter from `request()`.